# Galois automorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $f(X)=X^6-X^3-1 \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$  and $\rho=\sqrt[3]{\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}}$.

Given that $f$ is irreducible over the rationals and  $w$ the cube root of unity($w^3=1$,$w \neq 1$)
i proved that $L=\mathbb{Q}[w,\rho]$ is splitting field of $f$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and all the  roots of $f$ are $\rho,-w/ \rho, -w^2/ \rho,w \rho,w^2 \rho,-1/ \rho$

I also proved the existence of isomorphisms $\sigma$ and $\tau$ such that $\sigma(\rho)=-w/ \rho ,\sigma(w)=w^2$ and $\tau(\rho)=\rho,\tau(w)=w^2$
and the galois group of $L/ \mathbb{Q}$ is isomorphic with the dihedral group of $D_6$.

I've been asked to make a table with the values to $\rho ,w$ of each automorphism-element  in the galois group.

But i find a problem in calculating $\sigma^4(\rho)$ (thus and $\sigma^5(\rho)$)
because every element in galois group has to permute theo roots of $f$ and $\sigma^4(\rho)$ does not give a root of $f$ .

Can someone help me with this please?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your problem $\sigma^2(\rho) = \sigma(-\omega/\rho) =  -\omega^2/(-\omega/\rho) = \omega\rho$ , $\sigma^3(\rho) = \sigma(\omega\rho) = \omega^2\cdot (-\omega/\rho) = -1/\rho$, $\sigma^4(\rho) = \sigma(-1/\rho) = -1/(-\omega/\rho) = \rho$ which is certanly a root of $f$.

Comment: why is  $-1/(-w/ \rho) =\rho$ ?

Comment: Sorry the last equality is wrong it should be $\sigma^4(\rho) = \sigma(-1/\rho) = -1/(-\omega/\rho) = \rho\omega^2$ which is a root of $f$. This happens when writing directly in Latex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does:

$$\sigma\rho:=-\frac\omega\rho\implies \sigma^2\rho=\sigma\left(-\frac\omega\rho\right)=-\frac{\sigma\omega}{\sigma\rho}=-\frac{\omega^2}{-\frac\omega\rho}=\omega\rho\implies$$

$$\sigma^3\rho=\sigma\left(\omega\rho\right)=\omega^2\left(-\frac\omega\rho\right)=-\frac{\omega^3}\rho=-\frac1\rho\implies$$

$$\color{red}{\sigma^4\rho}=\sigma\left(-\frac1\rho\right)=-\frac1{-\frac\omega\rho}=\frac\rho\omega=\color{red}{\omega^2\rho}$$

Comment: you used the fact that $w^3=1$

Comment: @capo Yes, of course.